# Is it possible to capture return value of function used in std::call_once?

Tags: c++, mutex

Suppose I have a function returning an expensive object and I want it to call exactly once while having an access to return value of the function.
Is this achievable with `std::once_flag` and `std::call_once` or I need to go with boolean flags, etc..?

Simple example:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
shared_mempry_object openOrCreate(const char* name)
{
    shared_memory_object shm(open_or_create, name, read_write);
    return shm;
}
```

I there a way to call this function from some routine and ensure only calling once with mentioned primitives while maintaining return value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use a static function variable.

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
shared_mempry_object& openOrCreate(const char* name)
            ///     ^  return by reference to prevent copy.
{
    static shared_memory_object shm(open_or_create, name, read_write);
 // ^^^^^^ Make it static. 
 //        This means it is initialized exactly once
 //        the first time the function is called.
 //    
 //        Because it is static it lives for the lifetime
 //        of the application and is correctly destroyed
 //        at some point after main() exits.

    return shm; // return a fererence to the object
}
```

You can add some wrapper to guarantee clean-up at the end of the application.

Comment: Don't se how this did not cross my mind, long day probably..
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course it can also be manually destroyed earlier, but then it has to be either a) made a static class member or b) you would extend the function parameters to include the destruction operation or c) you would destroy the returned reference from outside the function. If the object type does not allow storing a destroyed status or it is expensive, you can wrap it into a smart pointer or a `std::optional` for it.